# javascript magic or my fail

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-api, ejs, google-api-js-client

I have an array of objects like this

```
{ 
    img: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dz_jeuWx3j0/default.jpg',
    title: 'The Deep End of Deep Learning | Hugo Larochelle | TEDxBoston',
    id: 'dz_jeuWx3j0',
    viewCount: '133219' 
}
```

and i put into html through `ejs`, `data` is my array

```
<% data.forEach((item, i, data) => {
     let str = '
       <div class="row my-3"> 
           <div class="col">
              <img src="' + item.img + '" alt="img" width="150" height="100">
          </div>
       <div class="col">
          <p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + item.id + '" target="_blank">' + item.title + '</a></p>
          <p>' + item.viewCount + ' views</p>
       </div>
    </div>'; %>
   <%- str %>
<% }); %>
```

and I don't know why, but sometimes this code shows me correct `viewCount` and sometimes I get `undefined`, and rest of properties displayed correct (`id`, `img`, `title`). Can anyone explain what's wrong?

Comment: Hi, it is likely that the viewCount does not have a value. You need to handle it in your code: `If item.viewCount`

Comment: @Terrance00 all of objects have `viewCount` with value

Comment: Could it be possible that if the viewCount is `0`, the value is undefined? Maybe print the item to the console to be sure - additionaly you can parse the number to text if it is there (Google it)!

Answer (score 0):

Google APIs dont return null values so if for some reason viewCount returns null then they just arnt going to return that parameter to you.

I also cant say if they would return 0 I have seen a few of their apis not return a count if the count is 0.

There is nothing you can do to change this other then a check for it in your code.